# upgrading not finished: How to correct issues or even finish the upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

I upgraded over night my computer. But this morning, not knowing that the life expectancy of my computer without energy cable plugged in is about 20 minutes :p, someone unplugged it and it shut down. So apparently, it was saying something about delete apps, I suppose that it was at the cleaning step. But there are two visible problems (I don't know if there are other, not visible...):

[image: white rectangles]

(the same happens for the batteries panel (charge level line) and the calendar panel (events))

And my windows are rectangle and with weird borders:

[image: rectangle with weird borders]

What would be best is to finish the install. But is it even possible?

Thanks a lot!

P.S.: With 13.10 I had ALWAYS a problem with maximising: by dragging the window on the upper bar to maximise it, at the moment that I released the window, there was ⅛ % risk that unity freeze. I always went then to tty1 and rebooted. Has someone already experienced this issue on 14.04? (Hopefully not! ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the borders and the white highlighting, it was due to Ambiance-dt that was enabled instead of Ambiance (system settings > appearance).

For the other problems, I did a new install, and no more freezing!